# bundle is identical to bundle install?

Tags: ruby, bundle, bundler

I have hit a very simple question as to Bundler command(http://gembundler.com/). Are there any differences between the following two? Or equivalent for them?

```
$ bundle
```

vs

```
$ bundle install
```

I checked both of Gemfile.lock generated after executing bundle(and bundle install). I surely confirmed both of Gemfile.lock were identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently they're identical. Bundler's default action is `install`. That's subject to change though.